# For google map v3, how to make sure if a MapsEventListener has been removed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, listener

`google.maps.event.removeListener(_listener);`

It doesn't make `_listener` as a null object. And there's no [static method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) to detect whether a listener is alive. Then, how to know it?

Comment: Wouldn't you know it has been removed since you're calling `removeListener`?

Comment: Null out `_listener` on the following line. `_listener = null;`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Now I do it this way, but I don't think it's elegant . So I asked this question.